# jQuery Ajax guess-type/predict issue

Tags: php, jquery

I am having to use jQuery I did not write, it was included in a template.

There is a function that does a 'guess type,' and uses the main navigation as the data to search against. As you type, pages within the site come up in the dropdown.

I need customer names from a database to dropdown, but I can't seem to get the function to work.

```
function searchInNav(s)
    {
        // Split keywords
        var keywords = s.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
        var nbKeywords = keywords.length;

        // Search links
        //var links = $('nav a'); // original
          var links = [];

        // LOAD CUSTOMERS AND EVENTS
        $.post('includes/ajax/global.php', { list: 'search', text: keywords },
            function(data){
                alert(data);
                links.push($(data));
            },
            "html"
        );

        var matches = [];
        links.each(function(i)
        {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var textMatch = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < nbKeywords; ++i)
            {
                if (text.indexOf(keywords[i]) == -1)
                {
                    textMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (textMatch)
            {
                // All keywords found
                matches.push(this);
            }
        });

        // Build results list
        var nbMatches = matches.length;
        if (nbMatches > 0)
        {
            var output = '<p class="results-count"><strong>'+nbMatches+'</strong> match'+((nbMatches > 1) ? 'es' : '')+'</p>';
            output += '<ul class="small-files-list icon-html">';

            for (var m = 0; m < nbMatches; ++m)
            {
                // Text with highlighted keywords
                var link = $(matches[m]);
                var text = link.text();
                var path = [text];
                for (var i = 0; i < nbKeywords; ++i)
                {
                    text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+keywords[i]+')', 'gi'), '<strong>$1</strong>');
                }

                // Path
                var parent = link;
                while ((parent = parent.parent().parent().prev('a')) && parent.length > 0)
                {
                    path.push(parent.text());
                }

                output += '<li><a href="'+matches[m].href+'">'+text+'<br><small>'+path.reverse().join(' > ')+'</small></a></li>';
            }

            return output+'</ul>';
        }
        else
        {
            return '<p class="results-count">'+settings.messageNoMatches+'</p>';
        }
    };
```

I keep getting errors with the links.each line, saying Object has not method each.

What do I need to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
//var links = $('nav a'); // original
```

$('nav a') makes a jQuery object of all a tags in nav. yours is just an array.

You need to modify that whole loop to handle it as an array and not a jquery object...

```
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++)
    {
        var text = links[i].toLowerCase();
        var textMatch = true;
        for (var n = 0; n < nbKeywords; ++n)
        {
            if (text.indexOf(keywords[n]) == -n)
            {
                textMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (textMatch)
        {
            // All keywords found
            matches.push(links[i]);
        }
    });
```

But I can't guearntee this modification above. The general concept is that you changed it from a jquery object to an array so you have to modify the loop accordingly.

Also, what is this:

```
links.push($(data));
```

Is data returning an expected dom id? like #some_div? Otherwise that $() makes no sense. It should just be data.